# Can we request unity to create an instance that does not implement interface?

Tags: unity-container

I have public class i.e. `public class Student` and i am currently instantiating it using `new i.e. Student st =  new Student()` keyword.

This class does not implement any interface.

Can i request Microsoft Unity to create an instance of this class?

I only know we can request IOC if that class implement interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can for example resolve it directly:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var s = container.Resolve(typeof(Student));
```

or you can register an Instance:

```
container.RegisterInstance(s);
```

which will be used if another class needs a Student instance in the constructor.